# Is Frank Wolfe a descent algorithm?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

A colleague was explaining to me that the [Frank-Wolfe algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank%E2%80%93Wolfe_algorithm) is a descent algorithm (i.e. its objective value decreases monotonically at each iteration). However, when I tried simulating it, my curve is not monotonically decrease, but does converge. It's possible I'm just a bad coder, but can someone point me to a proof somewhere that shows Frank-Wolfe is a descent method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it depends on how you choose $\gamma$. If you choose it using line search, then fine (see [this proof](http://www.math.chalmers.se/Math/Grundutb/CTH/tma946/0203/fw_eng.pdf)), otherwise I think in general, it does not. Consider the case $f(x) = x^2$ with $D = [-1,1]$. Starting from $x_0=1/2$ and using the rule $\gamma = \frac{2}{k+2}$ (fron the wikipedia page you linked), we have:
$$
\begin{array}{rcccc}
  k:   & 0 & 1 & 2 & \dots \\
  x_k: & 1/2 & -1 & 1/3 & \dots \\
  f(x_k): & \mathbf{1/4} & \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{1/9} & \dots \\
  s\,\nabla f(x_k): & s & -2 \, s & 2/3 \, s & \dots \\
  s_k: & -1 & 1 & -1 & \dots \\
  \gamma_k: & 1 & 2/3 & 1/2 & \dots \\
\end{array}
$$
As you can see the value of the cost function starts from $1/4$, then goes up to $1$ before decreasing to $1/9$.

Your proof seems to suggest that the algorithm is a descent algorithm for an arbitrary choice of $\gamma$. I think there is an error is the step:

> Since $s^*$ is the solution of a convex optimization problem, we have
>   $\nabla f(s)^T(x-s)\geq 0, \forall x\in D$.

In fact, this would hold if the function being minimized was $f(s)$ while $s^*$ is the solution of the tangent problem "$\operatorname{minimize} \nabla f(x_k)^T s$".

Comment: Ah yes I see my error, and your counter example makes sense! though, it seems to descend monotonically right after the first two iterations. Anyway though, this answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: totally found an error in my own proof. ignore this please.

Nevermind. I managed to prove it. Since I had some difficulty finding the proof, I'll just post the answer here.

The Frank-Wolfe algorithm solves

> min $f(x)$ 
>   subject to $x \in D$

using the iteration

$x^+ = (1-\gamma) x + \gamma s^*$

for some $\gamma \in (0,1)$, and $s^* = \arg\min_s \langle s, \nabla f(x) \rangle$.

From convexity we have

$f(x^+) \leq (1-\gamma) f(x) + \gamma f(s^*)$.

Since $s^*$ is the solution of a convex optimization problem, we have

$\nabla f(s)^T(x-s)\geq 0, \forall x\in D$.

[Edit: the optimality condition should be $\nabla f(x)^T(x-s)\geq 0, \forall x\in D$, not what's written. So this proof is incorrect.]

Finally, by first order condition, we have $f(s^*) - f(x) \leq \nabla f(s)^T(s-x)$.

Mix and match and we get $f(x^+) - f(x) \leq 0$.